# Why do we put login (with social media) buttons on the bottoms of login forms?

Tags: login

Like this: https://dribbble.com/shots/4414790-Modal-login-screen-Sketch-freebie

I never see them on top. 
Is there a reason?

Comment: What do you think the user experience will be if they are placed at the top? Can you propose a reason from your point of view just to help put some context into the reason that you asked the question?

Comment: StackExchange _sort of_ puts them on top... see https://stackexchange.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackexchange.com and click on _More OpenID options_... the "_Log in with..._" icons are on top, the manually-enter-an-OpenID box is below.

Answer (score 2):

It is about how to read content. While putting the form above, you emphasize your own login system over the others.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense! If that's the goal - as in, if we are trying to get users to login via a third-party service - do you think that's acceptable as far as best practices go?

Comment: Your answer is a bit brief can you expand on it?

Answer (score 0):

In mobile, buttons such as log in are placed where users would expect it to be. It can also be stated that, buttons being at the bottom is easier for users reach when the phone is held in single hand

Fitts law applies here